# How can i make a graphql request to my shopify graphql.json in nuxt express middleware using apollo?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, nuxt.js, shopify

So i made a express server middleware in nuxt and i made a graphql query that will get my data by product handle (gets product by slug) from shopify. But i keep running into 500 and 400 status code errors that don't provide where the issue is in my code. Sometimes the request even stays on pending. This is my code:

```
<script>
   //This is my vue component
   import axios from 'axios';
      // import { productByHandle } from '~/apollo/queries/productByHandle'
   export default {
       
        data() {
            return {
                product: {},
                handle: String
            }
        },
        
         async mounted() {
            this.handle = this.$route.params.handle
            // console.log(this.$apollo.query)
            // const query = await this.$apollo.query({
            //   query: productByHandle,
            //   variables() {
            //     return {handle: this.$route.params.handle}
            //   }
            // })
            // console.log(query) 
            console.log(this.handle) 
          // this.oneProduct = this.$apollo
          // console.log(this.$route.query)
          const result = await axios.post('/api/shopify/graphql')
          // , {
          //       params: {
          //           handle: "test"
          //       }
            // }
          console.log(result)
          //  this.product = result.data.product
        },
        
        // apollo: {
        //   $loading: true, 
        //   productByHandle: {
        //     prefetch: true,
        //     query: productByHandle,
        //     variables () {
        //         return { handle: this.$route.params.handle }
        //     }
        //   },
        // },

       
    }
    </script>
```

This is my express server middleware:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()
const axios = require('axios')
const url = require("url");
const gql = require('graphql-tag')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

router.post('/shopify/graphql', async (req, res, next) => {
  // const queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query
   const graphQuery = gql` query productByHandle ($handle: String!) {
     productByHandle(handle: "arcteryx-covert-lt-pullover-trui") {
         id
         title
        handle
    }
  }`;
  const shopify = await axios.post('https://<shop_id>:<shop_password>@<shop_name>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/products.json',{
    query: graphQuery,
  });

})




module.exports = router
```

index.js inside my routes file (to import the routes and use them):

```
const express = require('express')

// Create express instance
const app = express()

// Require API routes
const shopify = require('./routes/shopify')

// Import API Routes
app.use(shopify)

// Export express app
module.exports = app

// Start standalone server if directly running
if (require.main === module) {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000
  app.listen(port, () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`API server listening on port ${port}`)
  })
}
```

[Error i get in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ey0g.png)

So i have no idea how i can query my shopify data through my express middleware, i've been trying for 1.5 day now and im out of ideas (also i am new to server middleware, graphql and i am not very good in javascript yet.).

Comment: First off, start by trying the GraphQL in isolation. Download Insomnia and submit your query there.

Comment: Well i tested my query earlier and it works fine. I got my data through post man. The query it self isn't the problem.

Comment: separate your problems ... your middleware query doesn't look good, looks like variable dependent but not used [and not passed] ... test BE query separately ... then test data passed from FE, variables query and variables not passed (commented out)

Comment: I tested my query at first in my vue component using `apollo: {  productByHandle: query: productByHandle variables: { return {  this.$route.params.handle  }   }  }` and that worked fine. Then i moved it to my express middleware but there i couldn't use apollo (at least not that i am aware of since my js file doesn't accept any import statements :/. @xadm

Comment: check network request, it should be json with `query` and `variables` props, decode them (`variables.handle` only in this case?) and pass/use it the same way in axios request (after fixing bad query)

Comment: Can you add `console.log(shopify)` in your middleware and update your question with the error object?